# Docusign C# API calls for Connect

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the C# API provided by Docusign on GitHub and need to query Docusign for Connect message delivery failures. I've viewed the classes via Object Browser in Visual Studio and its not obvious which API & method to use. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DocuSign Connect endpoints have not been exposed in the current version of the [DocuSign C# client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client).  I've gone through and updated the [Omitted Endpoints](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/omitted_endpoints.md) list in the repo to reflect that.  This functionality will most likely be added in 2-3 months.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Sure, I've also updated the omitted endpoints list in the repo, apologies that was not accurate...